# Copy list objects from one list to another list based on properties

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have 2 lists, Say Student and Grades. Both  the lists have stuID in common.

```
class Student
{
    public int stuID;
    public string Name;
    // other properties
}

class Grades
{
    public int stuID;
    public string Grade;
    // other properties
}
```

How can I merge the results into another new list with All the grades per student say as below...

```
 public class StudentGradeDetails
    {
        public int stuID{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public GradeDetails[] gradeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var studentGrades = students.Select(s => 
    new StudentGradeDetails { 
        studID = s.studID, 
        Name = s.Name,
        gradeDetails = grades.Where(g => g.studID = s.studID).ToArray() 
   });
```

Comment: What if the grades list holds multiple items for each student. My goal is to create StudentGradeDetails for each student along with the grade details.

Comment: What is `GradeDetails` class?

Comment: never mind.. I was able to resolve it. by adding a filter on grades.